# VisualStudio 2015 - Only count hit and do not stop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am currently debugging a buggy piece of legacy code, which leaks Handles all over the place. For further investigation I would like to keep track of the lines in the code where a Handle is created and the corresponding line where it is closed, in order to see if they are in balance.

I tried to set a breakpoint in the corresponding lines and watch the hit count, which works fine. But it is tedious to always break there. Is there a way to make Visual Studio only count the hit but continue with execution?

Thankful for any advice. KR

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could set the break point to break only when the hit count is a multiple of a very large number, so it does not break in your example, or at least not often.

Debugging with conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio [2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/5557y8b4(v=vs.110)#specify-when-a-breakpoint-breaks-by-hit-count-expression-evaluation-execution-location-or-data-change), [2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/using-breakpoints#BKMK_Specify_a_breakpoint_condition_using_a_code_expression) and [2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#breakpoint-conditions).

Edit for future readers: as mentioned in your comment, the hit count will only be displayed when you have stopped execution, so make sure that some breakpoint will be hit at the time you want to examine it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this earlier, but did not use it, because VS did not update my currently hit count. Now I found that it only updates it (for all breakpoints) if any breakpoint is stopped at. So, what did the trick was: choosing a very large number (like you said) and setting a breakpoint which is stopped at for sure at the end of the program. This gives me the exact hit counts. [I have too less reputation to upvote... but I would!]

Comment: I used identical approach for another language, namely C#, and it works well!